# How do I stack subviews on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a graph view that I would like to overlay some buttons on. When I create a nib with buttons and add that as a subview after adding the graph, it just shows the buttons over a white screen.

```
GraphViewController *graphViewController = [[GraphViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:graphViewController.view];
GraphButtonViewController *graphButtonViewController = [[GraphButtonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GraphButtonView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:graphButtonViewController.view];
```

Comment: So a GraphButtonView will hold buttons? And that "GraphButton" will be inside the "GraphView"? If so, you can simply add GraphButtonViewController.view as a sub view of the graph view

[graphViewController.view addSubview:graphButtonViewController.view];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try making your GraphButtonView xib have a transparent background for it's (main) view?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that was the problem, thanks. One problem is that the button view blocks the functionality on the graph. Is the way to fix this by making the nib really small (only around the buttons)? Or should I try adding UIButtons programmatically or something.

Comment: I usually add overlay buttons programmatically.  That way, if I resize the graph, I can move the buttons to fit.

Comment: You can make the view container for the buttons any dimension you want. If you prefer to work in IB, then make sure the main view of the XIB has Status Bar - None. You can now re size the view.